# Parse date from multiple columns in pandas using parse_dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file in which month, day and year are in different columns. I want to combine them to one column and covert it in date format. I am trying to use parce_dates option in pandas read_table. But it is not working and giving me error `file structure not yet supported`

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%d-%y')
date = pd.read_table("date.txt", sep = ' ', parse_dates = {'date':['month', 'day','year']}, date_parser=dateparse)
```

My data looks like this:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM8Xj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `date_parser` arguments and it'll work just fine:

```
date = pd.read_table('date.txt', sep=' ', parse_dates={'date': ['month', 'day','year']})
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error as before after removing `date_parcer` argument

Comment: @SparkABC Which version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: pandas version: 0.23.4

Comment: @SparkABC The following works for  me on `pandas` 0.23.0: https://gist.github.com/Holt59/7eab90ff671c4a99c899ad92bd7e2a94 What error(s) do you get with this gist?

Comment: Sorry for late comment. The gist doesn't give me any error and works fine. Is it possible that text file is not supported for this operation? Are you able to use parse_dates while reading text file?

Comment: @SparkABC are you sure your file is correctly formatted? What do you get if you simply read the file without parse_dates?

Comment: If I don't use parse_dates, I am able to read text file correctly. The screenshot I put in question is after reading text file without parse_dates option. Is it working for you when you use it with text file?

Comment: @SparkABC It works perfectly if I load it from a file. Could you put the file you use somewhere so that I can use it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Read the data as a pandas DataFrame and create a new column with combined date

```
df = pd.read_csv('date.txt', sep = ' ')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['month','day','year']])
```

Comment: I ended up using this, however I asked question to understand why parse_date function is not working. Have you tried parse_date and encountered similar error?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing custom dates from multiple columns during pandas `read_` step is possible.

```
date_parser= lambda x,y,z: datetime.strptime(f"{x}.{y}.{z}", "%m.%d.%Y")
date = pd.read_table('date.txt', sep=' ', parse_dates={'date': ['month', 'day','year']}, date_parser=date_parser)
```