# How can I order the table by month and then show it in plot chart? Python

Tags: python

I want to Order the table by the year and by month.
Sort_values doesnt work for me.
after that I need to show it in plot line chart with month over time
How can I do it?

```
df10=df.groupby(['year','month'],as_index=False).Sales.sum()
    df10
year    month   Sales
0   2018    Apr 452546547.720000
1   2018    Aug 452830473.750001
2   2018    Dec 525888501.900000
3   2018    Feb 417589010.130000
4   2018    Jan 506665837.860000
5   2018    Jul 527113871.520000
6   2018    Jun 489527703.960000
7   2018    Mar 471807206.670001
8   2018    May 517740285.600000
9   2018    Nov 417862539.330000
10  2018    Oct 441153829.710001
11  2018    Sep 450298873.800000
12  2019    Apr 440397073.890000
13  2019    Feb 408684717.060001
14  2019    Jan 511212275.310001
15  2019    Mar 455560627.320000
16  2019    May 571120956.510000


sns.lineplot(x='month',y='Sales',data=df10)
```

[image]

Comment: Why does `sort_values()` not work? I guess because the months are strings, not numbers?

Comment: You should convert the two columns to a proper date(time) column. `pandas.to_datetime` should be able to handle multiple columns (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581817/parse-date-from-multiple-columns-in-pandas-using-parse-dates ), but you may need to specify a format because of the month abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

'To sort by month, you need to have mont has number, or sorted string text. Either way, refer below to my code to get month as number, then plot the df however you like.

```
from time import strptime
df['month_num'] = [strptime(x,'%b').tm_mon for x in df['month']
df = df.soft_vlaues(['year', 'month_num')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data['y-m'] = data['year'].astype(str) +'-'+ data['month']
data['y-m'] = pd.to_datetime(data['y-m'])
sns.lineplot(y='Sales',x='y-m',data=data)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Instead of 2018-01, 2018-03. You can also get 2018-JAN,2018-MAR. Check to_datetime on pandas for that

Answer (score 0):

When sorting by dates, you first need to convert your data to datetime using datetime.date(year, month)

[the key parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas.Series.sort_values) helps you with that.

```
df10.sort_values(key=lambda e: datetime.date(e["year"], e["month"]))
```